# Use multiple themes in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

Is it possible to start 2 Visual Studio instances, each with a different theme? for example, one with light theme and the other with dark?

Seems [this is possible in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52514491/different-theme-per-window-in-visual-studio-code), I wonder if there's a solution for Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the article
[Differentiating Visual Studio instances](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/differentiating-visual-studio-instances/),
author Mads Kristensen described how he was inspired by the
[Peacock extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnpapa.vscode-peacock)
for VS Code and the matching (now removed)
[Visual Studio feature request](https://web.archive.org/web/20220725213131/https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Per-SolutionFolder-Color-Theme/608136?space=8&ftype=idea)
(archived article).

He has written as a result the extension
[Solution Colors](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.SolutionColors):

> Allows you to associate a color with a solution or folder and display it in various locations within Visual Studio. Inspired
> [...]
> To enable colorization, open a solution or folder and right-click it to select the Set Solution Color submenu. From here you can choose between a list of predefined colors matching the color palette used for colorizing document tabs.

[image]

Comment: thank you very much, now different branches are more obvious!